# Are there any screenshots of Sherston Software's Around the World in 80 Days for Acorn Archimedes?

Tags: identify-this-game, acorn

I've been trying to track down an educational game I played at primary school. This was in the UK, and would have been around 1994 to 1996. The game was based on Jules Verne's Around the World in 80 Days; as I recall, you played as two children following the same route that Phileas Fogg took around the world, with various educational minigame/puzzle style activities at certain points of the game. The only one I remember at all clearly is one of the final ones; you are in a hot air balloon, and need to jettison items to stay aloft, by selecting the heaviest item from the list. I think some of the listed items were a teddy bear (possibly) and a cello (certainly).

We used to play the game in pairs over several sessions, so I believe the game had some way of storing each student's progress; I think my friend and I might have been the first (only?) pair to complete the game and make it all the way around the world.

Searching the internet for the game the only potential match I have found is [Sherston Software's Around the World in 80 Days](https://www.computinghistory.org.uk/det/12145/Around-the-World-in-80-Days/) for the Acorn Archimedes. This fits the time period, and it's educational software from a UK based company, which also fits. But I've been unable to verify as I can't find any screenshots or gameplay videos online, or anyone mentioning anything about the game. There are a few images of the game discs and associated material:

[image]

but these don't ring any bells for me, other than a vague recollection that we did have to switch discs at some point. Is anyone able to direct me to some screenshots from this version of the game, so I can check if it's the game I'm remembering?

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you remember? It might be a good idea to reformat this to focus strictly on what you remember (and what has been excluded).

Comment: I can understand this would be perplexing and vexing Showsni - there's a lot of matches and screenshots for the DOS game of the same name which has the player using cartoon artist tools to solve puzzles, but that is a completely different game to the one you're looking for, right?

Comment: @knol Yes, the EA Kids Paintbox Pals DOS game is a completely different one.

Comment: @Raffzahn Yes, I think it would need someone who'd played or seen the Sherston game to be able to confirm - does this game include the hot air balloon weight minigame, and are the protagonists two children following the trail of Phileas Fogg.

Comment: @Showsni: I can't find a place to download that title from. Some Archimedes games are available, but not this one. You could buy a disk and image it yourself, or try to ask people in the community about downloads. Of course, copyright is a touchy subject for some. [This forum](https://stardot.org.uk/) covers 32-bit RISC-OS software and looks active.

Comment: Maybe this Stardot user could help? https://stardot.org.uk/forums/viewtopic.php?p=263557&sid=7340a6e164a3bd7c09814912aaf44045#p263557

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be much about this game on the Internet. I can find two sources:

1. [Acorn User's April 1994 issue](https://archive.org/details/AcornUser1994Magazine/AcornUser9404/page/n15/mode/2up) has a screenshot and a brief news item about the game, telling us that the player characters are two children, Freddie and Francis (a boy and a girl, both descendants of Phileas Fogg himself), and showing the in-game art style using the Golden Gate Bridge to illustrate San Francisco.
2. [CJE Micros have "new old stock" for sale](http://www.cjemicros.co.uk/micros/individual/newprodpages/prodinfo.php?prodcode=SHE-AW80). If you were desperate to learn more, you could buy a copy from CJE Micros, and play it in an emulator to see if it really is the game you remember.

And you've already found [the Centre for Computing History](https://www.computinghistory.org.uk/det/12145/Around-the-World-in-80-Days/)'s copy of the game with box art on the web; again, they might be able to run the game in an emulator for you, and confirm or deny your memories.